# Windows Tomcat Service jvm -JvmSs parameter

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services, jvm, jvm-arguments

I see references to the JvmSs parameter in the [Tomcat Doco](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html)

```
--JvmSs     Thread stack size in KB
```

There is nothing in the Oracle JVM doco about this. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Is this an obselete Java parameter, in the format of Tomcat doco bitrot - or is this a specific Tomcat service running on Windows thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Tomcat specific thing, and I think it is specific to the Windows service launcher.  It is pretty clear that it maps to the JVM `-Xss` option.

There has never been a `--JvmSs` option on any Sun / Oracle JVM ... to my knowledge.

Comment: Actually it sounds more like the java -Xss option